# "DllRegisterServer entry-point" error when registering mongoc-1.0.dll and bson-1.0.dll

Tags: windows, mongodb, visual-studio, dll, lib

I had downloaded the files for MongoDB's C drivers and appear to have successfully compiled and installed them according to the publisher's instructions, using Visual Studio 2019 Community. However, after several attempts, the resulting **mongoc-1.0.dll** continues to fail to register with **regsvr32.exe**.

I've run the command as administrator, from the **system32** folder, as well as the **syswow64** folder, with and without the full path to the library, but it keeps throwing either the **module failed to load** error, or **the module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found**.

Here are the three attempts, all of which competed without  errors:

*attempt 1:*

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" \ "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\mongo\mongo-cxx-driver" \ "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:\mongo\mongo-cxx-driver" \ ..

cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo

cmake --build . --config RelWithDebInfo --target install
```

*attempt 2:*

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" \ "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\mongo\mongo-cxx-driver" \ "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=E:\mongo\mongo-cxx-driver" \ ..

cmake --build . --config Release

cmake --build . --config Release--target install
```

*attempt 3:*

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \ -DLIBBSON_DIR=E:\mongo\mongo-c-driver-1.17.4\src\libbson \ -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=E:\mongo\mongo-c-driver-1.17.4\src\mongoc \ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=E:\mongo\mongo-cxx-driver ..

msbuild.exe ALL_BUILD.vcxproj

msbuild.exe INSTALL.vcxproj
```

What could I be doing wrong? TIA.

---

**UPDATE:**  Dependency Walker showed these errors:

```
At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
```

I have no clue how to proceed. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: `register32.exe` or `regsvr32.exe`? Can you analyze your built module with something like `dependency walker` to find out if it contains `DllRegisterServer` exported function and that all imported modules are found?

Comment: @nevilad Yes; it's __regsvr32.exe.__ Where should the __DllRegisterServer__ function be? Because there's a ton of source files for the Mongo driver build.

Comment: Dependency walker analyzes the binary, not sources. It will show you all exported functions. DllRegisterServer must be there to allow regsvr32.exe to register the binary.

Comment: @nevilad I see. I'll give it a try. What would the recourse be if it's not there?

Comment: Find out why the function is not exported. Since this function must have this name in exports, you should search this name in sources and check why it is not exported (maybe there are comments or conditional compilation that explain why it can be so).